# extract date from file name using SSIS expression

Tags: ssis

HT,
Using Microsoft SSIS.

I have a input CSV file called - **LatLong_WD_Locations_06-21-2021**.
I want to extract date from this file name in **20210621** format using SSIS expression and store in to a variable called **v_FileDate** which is **Int32** type.variable **v_FileName** is a **string** type.

I tried with

```
(DT_I4) REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "_", 2)+1,10),"-","")
```

but its not working.

Can I have some help here, please.

TIA

Comment: Some work around -Working for me (YYYYMMDD)

(DT_I4)( REPLACE(RIGHT(@[User::v_FileName], 5),"-","")+REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "_", 3)+1,2),"-","")+REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "_", 3)+3,4),"-",""))

Answer (score 2):

Almost there.  You specified 2 for the occurrence argument in [FINDSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) expression.  So it is finding the `_` before Location in the file name giving you a result of `Locations_`.  Since that is not a integer it is throwing an error.

Change the 2 to a 3:

```
(DT_I4) REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "_", 3)+1,10),"-","")
```

The above would account for if the V_FileName has a file extension.  It would not get you the final format of yyyyMMdd.  See below...

You could also simplify and use [RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/right-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) expression.  Get the right 10 characters of the string and then replace:

```
(DT_I4) REPLACE(RIGHT(REPLACE(@[User::v_FileName], ".csv",""), 10),"-","")
```

I updated the above statement to account for if v_FileName had an extension.  That still does not give your final format of yyyyMMdd. See below...

Those 2 expressions above will get the date out of the v_FileName, but in format MMddyyyy.  Now you will have to parse out each part of the date and put it back together using one of the above statements. The example below is using the one with RIGHT:

```
 (DT_I4) SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RIGHT(REPLACE(@[User::v_FileName], ".csv",""), 10),"-",""), 5,4) 
+ SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RIGHT(REPLACE(@[User::v_FileName], ".csv",""), 10),"-",""), 1,2) 
+ SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RIGHT(REPLACE(@[User::v_FileName], ".csv",""), 10),"-",""), 3,2)
```

Comment: filenames usually have extensions. So account for that as well.

Comment: also he wants to change format to yyyyMMdd

Comment: Thanks @KeithL ,
This is working but output is not as I needed.
```
(DT_I4) REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "_", 3)+1,10),"-","") 
```
output- 6212021 (MMDDYYYY)
Required format - 20210621 (YYYYMMDD)

Please suggest.

Comment: I see others have gotten the answer.  I updated this just so it is complete. @KeithL missed that, thanks for the feedback.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever have `Date` on the last 10 positions in file name solution is very simple. But if that is not case, write me below in a comment and I will write a new expression.

Solution explained step by step:

1. Get/create variable `v_FileDate` with value `LatLong_WD_Locations_06-21-2021`

2. For check create `DateString` with expression

```
RIGHT( @[User::v_FileDate], 4) + 
LEFT (RIGHT( @[User::v_FileDate], 10), 2) + 
LEFT (RIGHT( @[User::v_FileDate], 7), 2)
```

3. Create a final variable `DateInt` with expression

```
(DT_I4) @[User::DateS]
```

**How variable should like:**

[image]

---

**Or you can with a single variable (It would be better with a single variable).**

```
(DT_I4) (
    RIGHT( @[User::v_FileDate], 4) + 
    LEFT (RIGHT( @[User::v_FileDate], 10), 2) + 
    LEFT (RIGHT( @[User::v_FileDate], 7), 2)
)
```

### Final Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using script task...

1. Pass in v_FileDate as readwrite
2. Pass in v_FileName as readonly

Code:

```
//Get filename from SSIS
string fileName = Dts.Variables["v_FileName"].Value;

//Split based on "_" 
string[] pieces = fileName.Split('_');

//Get the last piece [ref is 0 based and length is actual]
string lastPiece = pieces[piece.Length -1];

//Convert to date
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(lastPiece, "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//Convert to int from string converted date in your format
Dts.Variables["v_FileDate"].Value = int.Parse(d.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some work around -Working for me in (YYYYMMDD) format.**

**Thanks @keithL**

(DT_I4)( REPLACE(RIGHT(@[User::v_FileName], 5),"-","")+REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "*", 3)+1,2),"-","")+REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::v_FileName],FINDSTRING( @[User::v_FileName] , "*", 3)+3,4),"-",""))